# Forward data to component in Ractive.js

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

Let's say I want to dynamically generate a collection of Ractive components from an array that specifies the data that should be passed to each instance:

```
var items = [
    { data: { foo: "bar1" } },
    { data: { foo: "bar2" } }
];
```

Is there any way to forward that data to component so that it sees it as it's data - not as a property called "data".

```
{{#each items}}
    <Component __data__="{{data}}" />
{{/each}}
```

The reason for this is that I want to be able to easily reuse Components for both dynamic list and without dyanmic lists:

```
<Component foo="bar3" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This PR](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/pull/2174) would do exactly that via:

```
<Component this='{{data}}'/>
```